# Getting SSL PROTOCOL ERROR in Socket.io:

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sockets, ssl

i am using socket.io in my application. when i am working without ssl certificate, it is working fine. i am new to nodejs,i don't know,how to add ssl certificate. There is i am using angularjs for front end and nodejs for backend. socket.io call is not working,i am getting ssl protocol error. please help me,what i am doing wrong ?

My angularjs code

```
var socket = io.connect('https://localhost:3001', {
      'reconnect': true,
      'reconnection delay': 500,
       'secure' : true
    });
```

My nodejs code

```
var fs = require('fs');
var PeerSync = require('./lib/PeerSync');
var HistoricSync = require('./lib/HistoricSync');

var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var express = require('express');
var program = require('commander');

var config = require('./config/config');
var logger = require('./lib/logger').logger;
program
  .version(config.version);
// setup headers
require('./config/headers')(expressApp);

// setup http/https base server
var server;
if (config.enableHTTPS) {
  var serverOpts = {};
  serverOpts.key = fs.readFileSync('./etc/test-key.pem');
  serverOpts.cert = fs.readFileSync('./etc/test-cert.pem');
  server = https.createServer(serverOpts, expressApp);
} else {
  server = http.createServer(expressApp);
}
```